# What is going on in this recursive python subset sum function; specifically the or statement that is being used within an if/else block?

Tags: python, recursion, subset-sum

Basically, part of my CS homework is to create a function that takes in an argument list of nonnegative numbers L, and returns whether or not a subset of these numbers add up to a given exact amount (another argument). I already created the solution, but really did it following the 'hints' given to me saying it involved using an 'or' statement where you include a recursive function that excludes the last element and another one that includes it. I came up with this:

```
def exact_change(target_amount, L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        return target_amount == 0
    else:
        print('target_amount is', target_amount, 'list is now', L)
        return exact_change(target_amount, L[1:]) or 
        exact_change(target_amount - L[0], L[1:])
```

It passes all the assert tests, and I tried understanding what exactly was going on by adding print statements. This actually made it more confusing to me.

```
In [17]: exact_change(42, [25, 16, 2, 15])
target_amount is 42 list is now [25, 16, 2, 15]
target_amount is 42 list is now [16, 2, 15]
target_amount is 42 list is now [2, 15]
target_amount is 42 list is now [15]
target_amount is 40 list is now [15]
target_amount is 26 list is now [2, 15]
target_amount is 26 list is now [15]
target_amount is 24 list is now [15]
target_amount is 17 list is now [16, 2, 15]
target_amount is 17 list is now [2, 15]
target_amount is 17 list is now [15]
target_amount is 15 list is now [15]
Out[17]: True
```

What is specifically confusing to me is how the program picks which recursive function to use--another thing I'm confused about is how the list expands when it's being sliced. Maybe I'm looking at these statements wrong? Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: You have two recursive calls, so the function is run in a DFS-like order. The list seemingly growing is accounted for by the backtracking. Try printing another argument to show which branch you're on, e.g. `exact_change(target_amount, L[1:], 1) or exact_change(target_amount - L[0], L[1:], 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the short-circuit feature of the logical OR statement, found in most programming languages. For a general statement `b1 OR b2`, the expression `b1` is evaluated first.  If it evaluates to `true`, the whole statement evaluates to `true`.  If not, `b2` is evaluated and the whole statement evaluates to the result of `b2`. Not that if `b1` evaluates to `true`, `b2` is never evaluated. This is often used in other contexts.

Applying this to your code, you get the function calls as in your output.